# How to find all unanswered questions in a particular tag asked within the last year?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, search

I can select unanswered questions with a particular tag.

How do I then select from those, the questions asked within the last 2 years, ordered by votes?  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnonparametric%5d%20answers%3a0%20created%3a2y.. I.e. you type `[nonparametric] answers:0 created:2y..` in search. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching for details.

Comment: Does Glen_b's answer answer your question? It certainly looks like it does. If so, please consider accepting it. I see that you asked 16 Qs (https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22452/engrstudent) on Meta and only accepted 1 answer, even though many (perhaps most?) seem to have completely fine answers. 1/16 is a *very* low acceptance rate. I think it would be great if you could look through your 16 questions and accept satisfactory answers everywhere. Nobody earns reputation points on Meta, but accepting  helps to visually mark threads as "resolved". Thanks.

Comment: @amoeba - You answered the correct way in the comment, so it was yours and not his.  If you had made an answer I would select it.  It feels less meritocratic to give your points to him.  I will select his answer as you request.  Too often I ask because I am trying to do, and so I move quickly to the doing.

Comment: No problem, nobody earns rep point on Meta anyway :-)

Comment: I have looked through a sampling of my questions without answers, and there are some with no answers, and there are some where the answers are relatively unpalatable.  Cardboardy?  I have substantially changed my rate of meta questions without an accepted answer, but I am not sure I can push it much further.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edited to incorporate amoeba's suggested improvement of my answer)

Within CV you can pretty much get what you seek, for example

i. you can easily get all but one of the things you seek, for example if you type `[nonparametric] answers:0` into the search box and click the "recent" tab you get [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bnonparametric%5d%20answers%3a0), which is the most recent questions in the nonparametric tag with no answers. This uses only options you can see by clicking on "Advanced Search tips".

ii. if instead you put in the search box `[nonparametric] answers:0 created:2y..` (you need the two dots, see below*) and select the "votes" tab ... you get [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnonparametric%5D+answers%3A0+created%3A2y..) (you can find this option by scrolling to the bottom of the Advanced Search tips" revealed in the first suggestion and clicking the link there, which lists even more options). [[This seems to be pretty much what you asked for.]

Outside of the usual CV pages, another way to get what you want (but which allows you to filter in ways you can't within the usual search interface) would be via a data.SE query

http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/queries

* If you omit the dots after "2y" you get questions which have no answers, posted in the calendar year 2015, sorted by votes.

Comment: You can add `created:2y..` (as per https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching) and I think this will cover 100% of what OP wants. Together with ordering by votes, the link is https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnonparametric%5d%20answers%3a0%20created%3a2y.. (`https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnonparametric%5d%20answers%3a0%20created%3a2y..`)

Comment: @amoeba, +1, but also depends what you mean with "uanswered";  because the SE concept of it is a bit different: unanswered = no accepted answer or no positively scored answers.

Comment: @Andre yes, "answers:0" in a search is different from the "unanswered" tab; the first actually gives things with no answers.

Comment: @amoeba thanks; I have corrected my answer to incorporate your suggested improvement of my answer ... but actually it doesn't seem to quite do what is sought. I am editing again.

Comment: @amoeba ... oh, my fault! I missed the two dots at the end